# Removing from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In the DOM of my page there's a line like this:

```
<script src="text" src="something"> </script>
```

How is it possible to parse the DOM and if it finds the element with a `src="text"` attribute, remove it from the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

1. Attribute selector **[`[src="text"]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** for selecting element
2. **[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)** to remove it from dom

```js
$('script[src="text"]').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="something" src="text" src="something_else"></script>
```

Comment: you forgot the second set of quotes in your selector

Comment: @Adelphia As per documentation `value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.` https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: oh neat.. didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$('script[src="text"]').remove() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery-less answer is to use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector("script[src='text']").remove();
```

Supported by all modern browsers. For compatibility with IE < 8, you will have to use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or jQuery (which uses Sizzle for cross-browser compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Use `detach()` method if you will reinsert it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("script[src='text']").length);
  $("script[src='text']").detach();
  console.log($("script[src='text']").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="something" src="text" src="something_else"> </script>
```

or `remove()`.